# Assign a macro to a "Shape" inside shapegroup

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign a macro to each button inside a shape group on load.

Inside Module:

```vb
Private Const SideNavName As String = "SideNav"


Public Sub SetSideNavigationOnAllSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oShape As Shape
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        'check to see if sidenav shape/group exists in sheet
        If Common.ShapeExists(ws, SideNavName) Then
        
            ' get side nav
            For Each oShape In ws.Shapes(SideNavName).GroupItems
                ' only need the nav buttons not container
                If Left(oShape.Name, 3) = "Nav" Then
                    Debug.Print ws.Name, oShape.Name
                    oShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "btn 1" ' pull from DB
                    oShape.OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!FolderSelectorButton"  '  ERRORS OUT HERE
                End If
                '
            Next
        End If
        
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub FolderSelectorButton()
    Debug.Print 1
End Sub
```

Error:

> run time 1004 application-defined or object defined error

on `oShape.OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!FolderSelectorButton`

Comment: Do you get an error message, and if so on what line?

Comment: Error:  run time 1004 application-defined or object defined error

Comment: this line:  oShape.OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!FolderSelectorButton"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems VBA doesn't like setting the OnAction property for Shapes that have been grouped. Solution is to store details of the group, ungroup it, update the OnAction property then re-create the group.

Replace your two lines setting the TextFrame and OnAction of the oShape object with the following:

```
' save then ungroup the Shapes
Dim oShpGrp As Shape, sShapeNames() As String, i As Long
Set oShpGrp = ws.Shapes(SideNavName)
ReDim sShapeNames(1 To oShpGrp.GroupItems.Count)
For i = 1 To oShpGrp.GroupItems.Count
    sShapeNames(i) = oShpGrp.GroupItems.Item(i).Name
Next i
oShpGrp.Ungroup

' update Shape
oShape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "btn 1" ' pull from DB
oShape.OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!FolderSelectorButton"  '  ERRORS OUT HERE

' re-group the Shapes
Set oShpGrp = oShpGrp.Parent.Shapes.Range(sShapeNames).Group
oShpGrp.Name = SideNavName
```

This assumes that the group is a single-level group (ie it is not a group embedded within another group)

Comment: I can work with that.  Thanks tons!